# Cocos2d-js to create iOS game on a PC

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

Can I use cocos2d-js to make an Apple game on my Windows laptop?

I read somewhere that you can only create iOS games in mac. But if I download cocos2d-js will I be able to use it create an iOS game?

Comment: It is TECHNICALLY possible, but you would need a modified Windows computer that could run Mac OS X.  It would be highly preferable to just buy a used Mac, just make sure it has an Intel processor.

Comment: If it's anything like cocos2dx, you would probably be able to write the game in your PC, but you'd need to compile it through `cocos` on your Apple machine

Comment: If I were to get a mac, and develope a gme in mac, wil this game work for android devices? or you need a windows computer to create android games?

Answer (score 1):

Cocos2d-JS engine is the HTML5 version of Cocos2d-x, which includes Cocos2d-html5 and Cocos2d-x JavaScript Binding so you can write code in javascript and develop for web,iOS & Android

Basically its a engine to develop cross-platform games, so you can develop games using cocos2d-JS from any platform Windows, MAC , Ubuntu.

Now To compile for web again you can do it from any platform ,

For Android you have to setup the Android Dev environment (Eclipse or Android Studio , SDK , NDK ) on the respective platform

For iOS you need Xcode , Xcode is only available for MAC OS that's why you need MAC , you can use VMWare to setup MAC OS on your windows PC if you have a good configuration